# iCloud refusing to sync

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization

I am currently struggling to get my MacBook Pro to sync my Documents & Data.

Here's what I tried:

- Completely wiping my MacBook
- Removing the CloudDocs folder
- Restarting my Mac many times
- Changing my Computer's name in Sharing in System Preferences.

I have had no luck.

My Desktop & Documents folder has remained empty and is not syncing, however my other apps are syncing fine.

[image: My iCloud Documents folder remains empty.]

Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: How long are you waiting for the sync?  Depending on how much data you have, it could take up to 48 hours of you not using the device.  Have you checked on icloud.com to verify your data is actually in iCloud?

Comment: @fsb Hi, thank you for reaching out. It's been 8 days I've been waiting iCloud Drive to sync up my docs and it has not done so. And yes, all my documents and files are on iCloud.com.

Comment: Wow, 8 days is too long. Do you have any antivirus, vpn, or software like little snitch that could be blocking the sync?  Do you have any other Apple devices you can use to validate the sync works for them?

Comment: @fsb Hello! Yes indeed haha. No, there's no sort of Antivirus or similar installed. I even went as far as completely wiping Macintosh HD and reinstalling macOS and still no joy. On my iPhone, I created a folder and it synced perfectly (it appeared on iCloud.com).

Comment: And that time frame should be done with the power on and the computer awake - and there's little indication it's working until it finishes